# Resolving Case When Doubling Up

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, case-when

I have been looking everywhere for an answer for this, and I cannot seem to find an answer.  I really do apologize if this a duplicate, but I really need some help

I have a very simple case when statement, which is working as expected

```
CASE WHEN  Table.Expirydate < @Today AND CON.Column IS NULL
     THEN count(ContactID) OVER (PARTITION BY column,type ) END
```

However, it is produces two lines

Results are

```
NAME    COUNTID CLAUSE
A       10      5
A       10      NULL
B       1       1
B       1       NULL
```

Ideally I would like to remove the line with the nulls -

```
NAME  COUNTID  CLAUSE
A     10          5 
B     1           1
```

I have tried a suggestion to use `CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN  END)`  but this errors.  I have used a coalesce this does not work.  There is probably something very obvious I missing!

Just to clarify it not easily put in the where clause as I have a number of these in my stored procedure.

The basic part of the select statement is as follows -

as my select Statement

```
Table1.Id AS NAME

,Count(ConID) OVER (PARTITION BY Table1.Id2) AS COUNTID

,Case When Statement AS CLAUSE
```

Comment: Please read the documentation on how to as a question (https://stackoverflow.com/help) and proceed to format your question appropriately (your code segments should be clearly marked as such) to aid readability.

Comment: use the case in where clause filter like select * from abc where (1= CASE WHEN  Table.Expirydate < @Today AND CON.Column IS NULL
     THEN 1 END)

Comment: that `case expression` by itself cannot create extra rows, provide the complete query not small snippets from it.

Comment: Could you show the whole actual query in the question, with real column names ? It is difficult to stick together from the pieces you showed, the first snippet uses different column names than the others,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is tempting to just add a `WHERE` clause with:

```
WHERE Table.Expirydate < @Today AND CON.Column IS NULL
```

However, doing this changes the data used for the window function.

Instead, use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (<your query here>) t
where <expr> is not null;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for everyones answers/comments. I will not be able to post my actual code on here as its work,     I will try a subquery again.  Thanks anyway